# Making two other div's change color when hovering over main div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 3 div's. I would like to change some stuff in 2 of those div's when I hover over the "main"/"first" div. I am really, *really* trying to avoid any use of Javascript/jQuery, here.

I am pretty sure this can be done, I vaguely remember reading about it a while ago but I cannot find the link again and my previous searches have not helped, probably because I might not be using the correct terms.

Here's the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/KvAdH/5/):
HTML:

```
<div id=one></div>
<div id=two></div>
<div id=three></div>
```

CSS:

```
#one{background-color:blue;width:50px;height:50px;float:left;}
#two{background-color:green;width:50px;height:50px;float:left;}
#three{background-color:red;width:50px;height:50px;float:right;}

#one:hover > #two + #three { background-color: yellow; }
```

Can someone please help? How do I make the other *two* divs change color when I hover over the first one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DO you mean like this?

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h944n/)

```
#one:hover ~ #two , 
#one:hover ~ #three  
{ background-color: yellow; }
```

Issue is that `>` mean it is immediate descendant selector and combination of selector with `+` won't work.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! This is perfect! Now my migraine should go away soon :-D

Comment: @psl 
my problem is that you have 2 divs,u hover onto one ,both the divs get highlighted,then you hover onto another both the divs get highlighted. but in your case only first part is happening !! can u get me a solution for that.

Comment: why does this fail when you switch the order of the two divs ?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 things to know.

First, you cant select 2 elements by id in one "rule", you need to use comma.

Second, `>` mean children of and `+` right next to of. So your rule mean :

```
#one
    #two //Children of #one
    #three //the selected one (children on #one)
```

Your rule should look like this :

```
#one:hover ~ #two, #one:hover ~ #three { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for explaining this! Now I know what those doody things really mean :-)