# Hover affecting elements that aren't siblings

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following situation: 
I have three divs inside a container. If I hover one of these divs the other two should change their appearance. 
Here is a fiddle showing my current situation: 
http://jsfiddle.net/SUBHUMAN/gb63t8sb/ 
As you can see it only affects the elements that appear after the hovered element in the DOM.
Is there any way to achieve the wanted behaviour preferably without using JavaScript?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="one">
    </div>

    <div id="two">
    </div>

    <div id="three">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#two {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#three {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#one:hover ~ div {
    background-color:black;
}

#two:hover ~ div {
    background-color:blue;
}

#three:hover ~ div {
    background-color:purple;
}
```

Comment: In the "real" project I'm working on there is a <p> element with text in each div. If one div gets hovered only the <p> in this div should be displayed -> I wanted to set the other ones to "display: none".

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/gb63t8sb/3/ ?

Comment: Did you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660719/making-two-other-divs-change-color-when-hovering-over-main-div

Comment: @DPac this selector gave me the best functionality for the first div (was trial and error).

Comment: @GobSmack this solution is not what I'm looking for since it runs in the same difficulties when you try to make hovering over the other elements work. It also doesn't work for elements that are before the hovered element in the DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that currently CSS does not support *previous* siblings selector, so your attempt with [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) (`~`) will lead only to selection of *next* siblings of the hovered element.

However, you can simulate the behaviour with the following:

```
#container:hover > :not(:hover) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gb63t8sb/4/

Comment: Although this answer is really good, it doesn't say how to change the `background-color` according to what `div` was hovered. The original question tries to set the others to `black` when the first one is hovered, `blue` if the second one, and `purple` for the last one.

Comment: In my real project this functionality is fine. But it would be interesting to see if it is possible to set the different colors.

Comment: @SUBHUMAN I don't think it will be anyhow straightforward with the current version of CSS. You have to use JavaScript to do the job in order to save time and space, as possible CSS solution may become massive and far not flexible.